# Retrieving a string table from another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, localization, assemblies

I have an assembly, let's call it A, which contains a string table for localizing strings as a  resource. I also have another assembly, called B, which A references to, that has to use those string tables that are contained in assembly A.

The way the code is referencing that string table now in assembly A is this:

```
localResourceManager = new ResourceManager("languageControl", typeof(frm_SomeForm).Assembly);
string someString = localResourceManager.GetString("SomeStringTxt");
```

The form `frm_SomeForm` is part of assembly A.

How can I use that same `ResourceManager` in assembly B without having to include those same string tables as resources in assembly B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to assembly A that returns its ResourceManager.

Comment: The problem is that assembly B doesn't see assembly A.
I was thinking more on the direction of reflection...

Comment: If B does not see A then B cannot use anything in A.  What you want to do is not clear

Comment: Yeah even reflection isn't going to get around the problem of A not existing with respect to B. Be more specific about what you mean by "B doesn't see assembly A".  How can you expect to do anything with something you can't see?